# Clear Textbox when workbook is closed

Tags: excel, vba

In my Workbook I have a Worksheet which is hidden with password protection.

In Sheet1 I have a CommandButton control, which makes Sheet2 visible when the password is entered in TextBox1.

In my VBA Code, Sheet2 is hidden when I close the Workbook, but if I open it again the password is still visible in TextBox1.

Is there any possibility to clear TextBox1 when I close the workbook?

This is my code for when I close the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

This is my code for hiding the other sheets in the workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If TextBox1.Text = "password" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.PasswordChar = "*"
End Sub
```

Comment: You should have 2 buttons (1 for hiding and 1 for unhide)... since usually you don't need PWD just to hide. Also, erase the TextBox1 in CommandButton1_Click just after the If statement (when you clear the TextBox you set it to "" not " " -- no space)

Comment: @diem_L please add it as an answer, not as an edit to your post.

Comment: or `vbnullstring` in addition to @HuyPham's comment

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value = " "
End Sub
```